# How can I rotate labels in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a scatter graph with lables. I want to rotate lables - instead of horizontal position I want to see them vertically. I only saw q-s about rotating axis lables on Stackoverflow.

Sample:

```
mtdata <- mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "name")

ggplot(mtdata, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + geom_point() +
  geom_label(data = mtdata %>%
               filter(mpg > 20 & wt >3), aes(label = name))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `angle` parameter if you are ok using `geom_text`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtdata, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = mtdata %>% filter(mpg > 20 & wt >3), 
            aes(label = name), angle = 90, hjust = -1)
```

[image]

Unfortunately, `angle` is not available in `geom_label`.

Comment: that might be correct for geom_label, but there is still a proper solution for the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ggtext`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
mtdata <- mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "name")

ggplot(mtdata, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + geom_point() +
  geom_richtext(data = mtdata %>%
               filter(mpg > 20 & wt >3), aes(label = name), angle = 90)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>